# What shell is used to execute an ssh forced command

Tags: ssh

When you set a forced command against an authorised key, what shell is used to interpret that command and how do you change that shell?

If you add an authorised key with a command parameter like

```
command="ls -lah"
```

what shell is used to execute that command?

Answer (score 2):

The user's login shell will be used. Just try adding `command="echo $SHELL"`

Answer (score 1):

`man sshd` answers all your questions:

> **LOGIN PROCESS**
>
> When a user successfully logs in, sshd does the following:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. Runs user's shell or command.  **All commands are run under the user's login shell as specified in the system password database.**